# Solve $x^3y'= y^3 + 2xy^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

**I found** the following exercise:

$$\text{Solve: } \ x^3y'= y^3 + 2xy^2$$

---

**The idea** I used:

$$\text{Let } y(x) = x\cdot v(x)$$

After some computations:

$$\int \frac{\text{dx}}{x} = \int \frac{\text{dv}}{v(v^2+2v-1)}$$

After computing the integrals, it becomes:

$$\frac{\ln(|v^2 + 2v - 1|)}{2} + \frac{\ln(|v-\sqrt{2}+1|) -\ln(|v+\sqrt{2}+1|)}{2\sqrt{2}} - \ln(|v|) = \ln(|x|) + C$$

After that we will substitute back: $v$ with $\frac{y}{x}$, in the relation above.

---

**Question:** What magic could be applied to it as to be able to find $y = \text{...}$?

Did I have a bad start? How to solve this?

Thank you very much!

Comment: It is not always possible to get an explicit solution in these cases... I don't see any easy way of getting an explicit solution in this case.

Comment: This relation of the form $x=f_C(y/x)$ can be rearranged into one of the form $y=xg_C(x)$ iff you can invert $f_C(v):=e^C|v^2+2v-1|^{1/2}\left|\tfrac{v+1-\sqrt{2}}{v+1+\sqrt{2}}\right|^{1/\sqrt{8}}$ for fixed $C$, but I doubt such an inverse can be made explicit, or even exists outside suitable neighbourhoods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not always possible to get a general solution in an explicit form. In this case, I could not find any way of doing so. You can get a feel of what's going on by drawing the direction field.
[image]

Comment: Thank you! It seems $y$ could not be found in an explicit way.

Answer (score 1):

I continue to do some simplifications and I got that
$$y=\frac{x^2}{(y-x(1+\sqrt{2})(y-x(1-\sqrt{2})}$$

This is not really explicit solution. I hope that might help. By the way, I did not find find the constant when I did the partial fraction.

I want the integration part

$$\int \frac{\text{dv}}{v(v^2+2v-1)}= A\text{ln}v+B~ \text{ln}(v-(-1+\sqrt{2})+C~\text{ln}(v-(-1-\sqrt{2})$$

Comment: Thank you. I am trying to do the simplifications on my own just now.

Comment: @MMPP, check your integration again  on the left hand side in the last step . I think it is not correct

Comment: I just used an integral calculator and the result is the same.

Comment: @MMPP, I added the integration part. I found correct and helps you  please vote for it. Thank you,